# Asp.NET Core - Web Api - OpenApi Client method names

Tags: asp.net-core, openapi, swagger-codegen

I'm generating my Swagger/OpenAPI descriptor in my API:

```
services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo
                {
                    Title = "AthCoin API",
                    Version = "v1",
                    Description = "Ath coin interop service.",
                    Contact = new OpenApiContact
                    {
                        Name = "Ricerca e Sviluppo",
                        Email = "xx@my.it",
                        Url = new Uri("https://athena.srl/"),
                    },
                });
                
            });
```

... and in my client application (from Visual Studio) I'm generating automatically the client adding a "connected service".

On my API client each API method is mapped only using the action name:

- UserController.Create() -> is mapped as SwaggerClient.Create()
- ProductController.Create() -> is mapped ad SwaggerCient.Create2()

This is not useful.  Is there is a way to change the autogenerated client, adding the controller's name in the generated method name?

For example:

- UserController.Create() -> is mapped as SwaggerClient.UserCreate()
- ProductController.Create() -> is mapped ad SwaggerCient.ProductCreate()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add nuget package `Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Annotations` to your API project and mark your controller action with `SwaggerOperationAttribute` with `OperationId` parameter like this:

```
[SwaggerOperation(OperationId = "UserCreate")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Create()
{
    //whatever
    return Ok();
}
```

This will produce `"operationId": "UserCreate"` in the swagger JSON which in turn produces the desired `UserCreate` method in your generated client.

Comment: Hi, is there a way to do a naming template in startup ? Something like `options => options.OperationTemplate("[controller][action]")` ?

Answer (score 1):

This problem is discussed [in this MS blog post](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/generating-http-api-clients-using-visual-studio-connected-services/#well-described-apis-generate-better-client-code). Basically all you need to do is include the name in the routing attribute. Depending on how your routing is set up that might look something like:

```cs
[HttpGet("/orders/{id}", Name = nameof(GetOrder))]
public async Task <ActionResult<Order>> GetOrder([FromRoute] Guid id)
{
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to add in the `ConfigureServices` method of `Startup.cs`

```
services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
{
   ...

   c.EnableAnnotations();
});
```